# Not able to find values on between activities

Tags: android

I have two activities in my application say EMPID and INFO.
In EMPID activity I have one EditText say empid and in another activity INFO I have another EditText  Name.

I am able switch between these activities using Button in each activity.

But I want the value of empid to be shown when I switch to second activity and come back to first activity.

Can anyone help on these.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as for sending data from first activity to second:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     /*Create new Intent Object, and specify class*/
    Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setClass(EMPID.this,INFO.class);
    /*new Bundle Object, and put data in bundle object*/ 
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
     bundle.putString("EMPID ","empid");   
    /*Put Bundle object i.e bundle in intent*/ 
    intent.putExtras(bundle);  
    EMPID.this.startActivity(intent);
@Override
public void onResume()
{
  //SET EDITVIEW VALUE HERE to EMPID
    super.onResume();
}
```

In Activity INFO:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receivermain);
    TextView txtvwreceived=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtviewsender);
    /* Intent To obtain the  bundle object from EMPID */
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();  
    /* Obtain String from Intent  */
    if(bundle !=null)
    {
        /* Obtain Data from bundle object */ 
        String strdata = bundle.getString("EMPID");
        }
    }
```

and second way start your second Activity(INFO.class) using `startActivityForResult()` and override `onActivityResult` method in first activity (EMPID.class) for setting EditView value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult()` when you call the second activity. This will maintain the first activity in its previous state and you can have the `empid` maintained when you switch back to the first activity.

If you want to send the value of empid to second activity you can use `intent.putExtra()`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `putExtras` and `getIntExtras`

Below snippet will help you.

**EMPID.java**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,INFO.class);
intent.putExtra("id", empid);
startActivity(intent);
```

**INFO.java**

```
int empId=getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
```